# Display JSON from external website scrape on a chart 

Tags: php, javascript, json, charts, scrape

So I have been trying to scrape a websites data.asp file (which seems to be formatted in json) into my website to be displayed as a chart I seem to be able to get the json data but will not display as a chart in either googles chart API or fusioncharts I am not sure what I am doing wrong although in the examples on google and fusioncharts there json data is formatted differently would i have to change mine to meet that? and how would i do this to make sure that as the data.asp file is updated on the external website it is updated on mine also?

**EDIT:** Is there an easier way to get the data (aswell as on update) into a chart?

```
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Olympic Results</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="author" content="">

        <!--styles -->
        <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <style type="text/css">
          body {
            padding-top: 60px;
            padding-bottom: 40px;
          }
          .sidebar-nav {
            padding: 9px 0;
          }
        </style>
        <link href="css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">

        <!--HTML5 shim, for IE6-8 support of HTML5 elements -->
        <!--[if lt IE 9]>
          <script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->

        <?php
            if(!function_exists("curl_init")) die("cURL extension is not installed");
            $ch = curl_init("http://hosted.stats.com/olympics/medals_widget/data.asp?country=NZL");
            //Configuring curl options 
            $options=array(CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true, 
                           CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array('Content-type: application/json'));
            //Setting curl options
            curl_setopt_array($ch, $options);
            $pageData = curl_exec($ch);
            curl_close($ch); 
            //Cache the channel file 
            $cache_expire = 60*60*24*365;
            header("Pragma: public");
            header("Cache-Control: max-age=".$cache_expire);
            header('Expires: ' . gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s', time()+$cache_expire) . ' GMT');
        ?>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="Charts/FusionCharts.js"></script>

      </head>
      <body>
        <div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
          <div class="navbar-inner">
            <div class="container-fluid">
              <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              </a>
              <a class="brand" href="#">Olympic Results</a>

              <div class="nav-collapse">
                <ul class="nav">
                  <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                </ul>
              </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->

            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="container-fluid">
        <div id="chartContainer">FusionCharts XT will load here!</div>          
        <script type="text/javascript">

        <!--       
          var data = <?php echo $pageData; ?>;
          document.write(data);
          var myChart = new FusionCharts( "Charts/Column3D.swf", "myChartId", "400", "300", "0", "1" );
          myChart.setJSONData(data);
          myChart.render("chartContainer");

        // -->     
        </script> 
        <?php echo("$pageData"); ?>
            <footer style="padding-top:100px;">
            <hr>
            <p>&copy; Olympic Results 2012</p>
            </footer>

        </div><!--/.fluid-container-->

        <!-- javascript -->
        <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
        <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="js/bootstrap-transition.js"></script>
        <script src="js/bootstrap-alert.js"></script>
        <script src="js/bootstrap-modal.js"></script>
        <script src="js/bootstrap-dropdown.js"></script>
        <script src="js/bootstrap-scrollspy.js"></script>
        <script src="js/bootstrap-tab.js"></script>
        <script src="js/bootstrap-tooltip.js"></script>
        <script src="js/bootstrap-popover.js"></script>
        <script src="js/bootstrap-button.js"></script>
        <script src="js/bootstrap-collapse.js"></script>
        <script src="js/bootstrap-carousel.js"></script>
        <script src="js/bootstrap-typeahead.js"></script>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Forgot to add what the JSON looks like -

```
{"medals": { 
"Archery":[ { "stats_id": "83", "gold": "0", "silver": "0", "bronze":       "0", "total": "0" }], 
"Track & Field":[ { "stats_id": "83", "gold": "0", "silver": "1", "bronze": "0", "total": "1" }], 
"Badminton":[ { "stats_id": "83", "gold": "0", "silver": "0", "bronze": "0", "total": "0" }], 
"Basketball":[ { "stats_id": "83", "gold": "0", "silver": "0", "bronze": "0", "total": "0" }], 
"Beach Volleyball":[ { "stats_id": "83", "gold": "0", "silver": "0", "bronze": "0", "total": "0" }], 
"Boxing":[ { "stats_id": "83", "gold": "0", "silver": "0", "bronze": "0", "total": "0" }], 
"Diving":[ { "stats_id": "83", "gold": "0", "silver": "0", "bronze": "0", "total": "0" }], 
"Equestrian":[ { "stats_id": "83", "gold": "0", "silver": "0", "bronze": "1", "total": "1" }], 
"Soccer":[ { "stats_id": "83", "gold": "0", "silver": "0", "bronze": "0", "total": "0" }], 
"Fencing":[ { "stats_id": "83", "gold": "0", "silver": "0", "bronze": "0", "total": "0" }], 
"Handball":[ { "stats_id": "83", "gold": "0", "silver": "0", "bronze": "0", "total": "0" }], 
"Field Hockey":[ { "stats_id": "83", "gold": "0", "silver": "0", "bronze": "0", "total": "0" }], 
"Judo":[ { "stats_id": "83", "gold": "0", "silver": "0", "bronze": "0", "total": "0" }], 
"Modern Pentathlon":[ { "stats_id": "83", "gold": "0", "silver": "0", "bronze": "0", "total": "0" }],
"Rowing":[ { "stats_id": "83", "gold": "3", "silver": "0", "bronze": "2", "total": "5" }],  
"Sailing":[ { "stats_id": "83", "gold": "1", "silver": "1", "bronze": "0", "total": "2" }], 
"Shooting":[ { "stats_id": "83", "gold": "0", "silver": "0", "bronze": "0", "total": "0" }], 
"Swimming":[ { "stats_id": "83", "gold": "0", "silver": "0", "bronze": "0", "total": "0" }], 
"Synchronized Swimming":[ { "stats_id": "83", "gold": "0", "silver": "0", "bronze": "0", "total": "0" }], 
"Tennis":[ { "stats_id": "83", "gold": "0", "silver": "0", "bronze": "0", "total": "0" }], 
"Taekwondo":[ { "stats_id": "83", "gold": "0", "silver": "0", "bronze": "0", "total": "0" }], 
"Triathlon":[ { "stats_id": "83", "gold": "0", "silver": "0", "bronze": "0", "total": "0" }], 
"Table Tennis":[ { "stats_id": "83", "gold": "0", "silver": "0", "bronze": "0", "total": "0" }], 
"Volleyball":[ { "stats_id": "83", "gold": "0", "silver": "0", "bronze": "0", "total": "0" }], 
"Weightlifting":[ { "stats_id": "83", "gold": "0", "silver": "0", "bronze": "0", "total": "0" }], 
"Water Polo":[ { "stats_id": "83", "gold": "0", "silver": "0", "bronze": "0", "total": "0" }], 
"Wrestling":[ { "stats_id": "83", "gold": "0", "silver": "0", "bronze": "0", "total": "0" }], 
"Cycling":[ { "stats_id": "83", "gold": "0", "silver": "1", "bronze": "2", "total": "3" }], 
"Gymnastics":[ { "stats_id": "83", "gold": "0", "silver": "0", "bronze": "0", "total": "0" }], 
"Canoe":[ { "stats_id": "83", "gold": "1", "silver": "0", "bronze": "0", "total": "1"     }] 
}}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you will need to reformat your data. Get the data, convert it to a real javascript object and iterates over it and re-create the structure in the way your APIs understand. To convert JSON to an Object you cand use $.parseJSON method of the jQuery library.

Another thing. These data are obtained by your server and them redirected to your application?

**Edit:** Here is one example:

```
// this way, data is already an object
var data = { "medals": {
    "Archery":[{
        "stats_id": "83",
        "gold": "0",
        "silver": "0",
        "bronze":  "0",
        "total": "0"
    }],
    "Track & Field":[{
        "stats_id": "83",
        "gold": "0",
        "silver": "1",
        "bronze": "0",
        "total": "1"
    }] // more data here...
}};

// if data comes this way (a String), it needs to be parsed
var dataStr = "{ \"medals\": {" +
"    \"Archery\":[{" +
"        \"stats_id\": \"83\"," +
"        \"gold\": \"0\"," +
"        \"silver\": \"0\"," +
"        \"bronze\":  \"0\"," +
"        \"total\": \"0\"" +
"    }]," +
"    \"Track & Field\":[{" +
"        \"stats_id\": \"83\"," +
"        \"gold\": \"0\"," +
"        \"silver\": \"1\"," +
"        \"bronze\": \"0\"," +
"        \"total\": \"1\"" +
"    }]" + // more data here...
"}}";

console.log( data );

var obj = $.parseJSON( dataStr );
console.log( obj );

traverseObj(obj);

// traverses the object to see all its properties
function traverseObj( data ) {
    for ( var key in data ) {

        var value = data[key];

        if ( $.isPlainObject( value ) ) {

            console.log( "**key: " + key );
            traverseObj( value );

        } else if ( $.isArray( value ) ) {

            console.log( "key: " + key );
            var values = "";

            for ( var i = 0; i < value.length; i++ ) {
                var currValue = value[i];
                if ( $.isPlainObject( currValue ) ) {
                    traverseObj(currValue);
                } else {
                    values += currValue + ", ";
                }
                if ( values != "" ) {
                    console.log( " - value: " + value );
                }
            }

        } else {
            console.log( "key: " + key + " - value: " + value );
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/davidbuzatto/MysPe/

Comment: The facebook app thing is just there to show possible functionality, the json data i am just pulling in with curl and then trying to use that string for my chart. I just really need a way to display the data i get with a chart even if i need to edit it somehow, would be amazing if you could show me how to do it! Thanks, also i might remove the facebook thing from my example as not really relevant

Comment: So i don't need to parse my data as a string or do? When i pulled it from curl $pageData i set it to Content-type: application/json which i thought was already setting it as an object? or is that only done through $.parseJSON ?

Comment: It seems that you are writing the object using the object initializer syntax, so, when your code runs, it is already an object. If you get these data throught ajax, the response will be a String and you will need to parse it.

Comment: Do you think this would give the right outcome? var obj = <?php echo json_encode($pageData); ?>; It seems to be reading through the data and assigning it with the key values now that i have finished. Is it fine that there are spaces in these or should i be getting rid of them?

Comment: The spaces will be ignored by the parser, so you don't need to be concerned. If you want to economize network bandwich, you can get rid of them. Take a look at the code that is being generated to see what json_enconde is generating. If it have the first sintax os my example, ok, you don't need to parse. If it is generating a String, you will need to parse.